# Adobe LiveCycle Designer PDF automatic binds Text Field to User Input

Tags: pdf, forms, bindings

I've created a PDF form using Adobe LiveCycle Designer that has several pages. One of the fields users need to fill in is their names. I'd like to have their names appear automatically on the footer on every page of my PDF form when they've entered their names. I know I need to create a text field on the master page, but how to I bind that field to their input?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version you are using. However, you can use **action builder** under *tool menu* for such actions. I have checked it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a field in the master page and give it a name.
2. Create an input in the document where they will put their name.
3. Select the field created in #2 and under the Objects Menu select "Binding" then name it the EXACT SAME as the field in #1.
4. Also under the Binding tab under "Data Binding" select Use Global Data.
5. Check that the field in #1 is also set to Global Data.
6. The value for Field #1 should now always match the value typed in field #2.

Let me know if you have questions in the comments.